# Is this UPDATE table statement correct in an msdn topic

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have seen this type of UPDATE statement (just like insert statement) in the following msdn topic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz.aspx#Y2461

UPDATE statement:-

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers " &
  "(CustomerID, CompanyName) VALUES(@CustomerID, @CompanyName) " & _
  "WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID AND CompanyName = " &
  "@oldCompanyName", connection)
```

Is this statement correct or not?

I have tried executing it and it is giving syntax errors.

Comment: What were the errors you witnessed?

Comment: The sql looks ok, it depends on the context of what adapter is, how your parameters are set.  Can you post more code and error message

Comment: Try `adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers " & _
  "(CustomerID, CompanyName) VALUES(@CustomerID, @CompanyName)"  & _
  "WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID AND CompanyName = " & _
  "@oldCompanyName", connection)`. I do not know if this is a code format thing or not, but you do not have the newline character after the first and third lines

Comment: @Verrigo: You just added line continuations? I think you're missing a double-quote.

Comment: @Nr.Dissapointment. Thank you, i was drawing a blank and did not know how to call the "_" character. Also, thank you for pointing out the missing double-quote.

Comment: I've personally never seen `values` used in an `update` statement like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it should be:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET 
CustomerID = @CustomerID,
CompanyName = @CompanyName
WHERE
CustomerID = @oldCustomerID AND
CompanyName = @oldCompanyName
```

Or to be complete with your sample code, it should be:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers SET CustomerID = @CustomerID, CompanyName = @CompanyName WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID AND CompanyName = @oldCompanyName", connection)
```

Here is another reference for you and this situation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx

Answer (score 3):

That SQL appears to be correct for an `INSERT INTO` but not for an `UPDATE` It should read:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers" & _
    " SET CustomerID = @CustomerID, CompanyName = @CompanyName)" & _
    " WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID AND CompanyName =" & _
    " @oldCompanyName", connection)
```

That SQL is what one would call paramaterized, so that makes this code (lower in the snippet) very important:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add( _
  "@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID")
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add( _
  "@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "CompanyName")

' Pass the original values to the WHERE clause parameters.
Dim parameter As SqlParameter = dataSet.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add( _
  "@oldCustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID")
parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
parameter = adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add( _
  "@oldCompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "CompanyName")
parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
```

Comment: You are quite right! It should be `... SET col1 =  @val1, col2 = @val2`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see the syntax is not valid. The following gives `Incorrect syntax near '('.`

I suggest changing it as per [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183992/is-this-update-table-statement-correct-in-an-msdn-topic/5184048#5184048).

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
CustomerID INT, 
CompanyName VARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE 
@CustomerID INT, 
@CompanyName VARCHAR(10),
@oldCustomerID INT,
@oldCompanyName VARCHAR(10)

UPDATE Customers  (CustomerID, CompanyName)
VALUES(@CustomerID, @CompanyName)
WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID AND CompanyName = @oldCompanyName
```